# How to clone model instances in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want a user to be able to copy a blog post by some other user and save it as their own post. Basically, when a user copies a blog post I want to create a new blog post by copying all of the fields from the original blog post but without any changes in an original blog post. Following is the code which I tried. The problem with this code is that when I try to copy blog post it is changing the primary key of the original blog post. I want the original blog post to remain untouched. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
class CopyView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model = Entry
template_name = 'entries/create_entry.html'
fields = ['entry_title','entry_text', 'entry_input', 'entry_output']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.entry_author = self.request.user
    post = self.get_object()
    post.save()
    post.pk=None
    post.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are copying an existing entry, you are creating a new `Entry`, not updating. Therefore you'll want to subclass `CreateView` and use `get_initial()` to copy the values from the existing `Entry`. This will give you a filled in form that you can edit and save. Then, on submit, you only have to override `form_valid()` to assign the `entry_author` like you were doing above. You can pass in the existing entry pk with a url like this:

```
    path('entries/<int:entry_id>/copy/', CopyView.as_view(), name='entry_copy'),
```

Then in the view:

```
class CopyView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'entries/create_entry.html'
    fields = ['entry_title','entry_text', 'entry_input', 'entry_output']

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        existing_entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['entry_id'])
        initial['entry_title'] = existing_entry.entry_title
        initial['entry_text'] = existing_entry.entry_text
        initial['entry_input'] = existing_entry.entry_input
        initial['entry_output'] = existing_entry.entry_output
        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.entry_author = self.request.user
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        return response
```